# Find total number of customers having at least 5 orders (COUNT with JOIN, GROUP BY and HAVING)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I can find the total number of customers with at least 5 orders using an SQL COUNT with subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (

  SELECT c.id FROM customers as c
  INNER JOIN orders as o ON c.id = o.customer_id
  GROUP BY c.id
  HAVING COUNT(o.id) >= 5

) as temp
```

However I'd like to know how to achieve the same thing using the Rails active record query interface, if possible.

I have the code:

```
total_count = Customer.joins("INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id").group("customers.id").having("COUNT(orders.id) >= 5").count
```

But that results in a hash map of the customer id and number of orders, because the SQL that is generated looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, customers.id AS customers_id FROM `customers` INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id GROUP BY customers.id HAVING COUNT(orders.id) >= 5
```

Is there another way to achieve what I'm aiming for using Rails conventions? Or should I just build the raw query?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to join if you wanted some other info from customers, like their names or something like that. If count is all that you want just do a simple query on orders table:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(customer_id) >= 5
```

and count rows in the result set.